# modelling a relationship customer, conference, guest

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, poco

I've seen several examples of many to many relationships in EF using code-first, but I've run into a situation that I'm not sure how to solve.

Am trying to model this scenario

the entities are Customer, Guest, Event
1.) customer registers for events
2.) each customer has guests that he can bring to the event that he's registered for
     (eg if he has registered to event 1 and quantity is 3 he can assign 2 guests to that)

i tried this out using a simple scenario where i made a many to many relation b/w guests and events and it works fine, 
and i can add guests to events using the events.guests navigation property

But i need to have it work with customers, am havin a hard time wrapping my head around it, where would Customer fit into this model?

```
public class Guest
{
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    public string GuestName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
}
```

This generates a mapping table GuestEvent which has GuestId, EventId

from what i understand the mapping table should look like this with the added customer entity
customerId, EventId, GuestId
but how do i set that up?

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomerEvent` class needs to hold the `Guests`, because the guests need to be linked to a specific customer and a specific event. The same guest can go to different events, or be invited by different customers.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEvent> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
}

publix class CustomerEvent
{
    public int CustomerEventId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEvent> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
}

public class Guest
{
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    public string GuestName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEvent> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the super prompt answer, ill work on it more today and hopefully have a better idea, this definitely clears up things quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work: This assumes the relationship between a Customer and Event is 1:1, and all Name info is on the Guest object...

```
public class Guest
{
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
    public string GuestName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Patron { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: He said `customer registers for events` so the relationship between a Customer and Event is **not** 1:1.

Comment: yes thats correct , customer can have multiple registrations at the same time